# how do I avoid re-implementing the code being tested when I write tests?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec

(I'm using rspec in RoR, but I believe this question is relevant to any testing system.)

I often find myself doing this kind of thing in my test suite:

```
actual_value = object_being_tested.tested_method(args)
expected_value = compute_expected_value(args)
assert(actual_value == expected_value, ...)
```

The problem is that my implementation of `compute_expected_value()` often ends up mimicking `object_being_tested.tested_method()`, so it's really not a good test because they may have identical bugs.

This is a rather open-ended question, but what techniques do people use to avoid this trap?  (Points awarded for pointers to good treatises on the topic...)

Comment: To be really honest, what happens more often is that my implementation of `compute_expected_value()` ends up cleaner than the original `tested_method()`, so I'm tempted to back-port test code to the code base.  Then I have to devise yet another way to test the code...

Comment: You should back-port the cleaner code to the tested method. One of the benefits of testing is that it helps you improve the maintainability of the code you are testing. However, note that as mentioned in the answers below, you should not usually compute the expected value.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I gave into the temptation.  More comments in @vilas's post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually (for manually written unit tests) you would not compute the expected value. Rather, you would just assert against what you expect to be the result from the tested method for the given args. That is, you would have something like this:

```
actual_value = object_being_tested.tested_method(args)
expected_value = what_you_expect_to_be_the_result
assert(actual_value == expected_value, ...)
```

In other testing scenarios where the arguments (or even test methods being executed) are generated automatically, you need to devise a simple oracle which will give you the expected result (or an invariant that should hold for the expected result). Tools like [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), [Randoop](http://code.google.com/p/randoop/), [ASTGen](http://mir.cs.illinois.edu/astgen), and [UDITA](http://mir.cs.illinois.edu/udita) enable such testing.

Comment: I would like to do it that way.  The object being tested gathers data from many sources to produce a result.  I've mocked the source methods to generate known inputs, but the tested method() does complex things like taking the interquartile mean under certain circumstances.  

I guess the moral of the story is that if I need a method to compute the predicted results, then it's likely that tested_method() is already too complicated, that it should be refactored into smaller methods and that the smaller bits get tested individually.  

I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Well here are my two cents

a) if the calculation of the expected value is simple and does not encompass any business rules/conditions in there apart from the test case to which it is generating the expected result then it should be good enough... remember your actual code will be as generic as possible.
Well there are cases where you will run into issues in the expected method but you can easily pin point the cos of failure and fix it.

b) there are cases when the expected value cannot be easily calculated in that case probably have flat files with results or probably some kind of constant expected value as naturally you would want that.

Also then there are tests where in you just want to verify whether a particular method was called or not and you are done testing that unit.. remember to use all these different paradigms while testing and always remember **KEEP IT SIMPLE**

Answer (score -1):

you would not do that.

you do not compute the expected value, you know it already. it should be a constant value defined in your test. (or is constructed from other functions that have already been tested.)